# Pocketsphinx decoder adds words of its own

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`, `Python 2.7` & `PocketSphinx`.

I made a custom `dictionary`, `language model` using online `LM tool`. Using `pocketsphinx_continous` to decode the spoken voice gives me 100% accuracy. 
But using `PyAudio`to record sound in `Python` recognises the text but adds 'A' and 'AND' with the main context as shown in the images below
[image: PocketSphinx_Continuous]
[image: PocketSphinx in Python]
How to cure it?

Comment: You need to provide files for analysis.

Comment: Dictionary: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69889915/8143.dic
LM: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69889915/8143.lm
STT: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69889915/STT.py

Comment: Please provide audio file in question. Please provide files in a single archive to download, not a collection of links.

Comment: Here is everything:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69889915/Sample.tar.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the reduced accuracy is that you've added an artifical zero-silenced region around the utterance and that corrupts spectrum and reduces accuracy. Stop doing that. Instead, just recognize the sound you have recorded.

If you still need to decode zero-silenced regions, you need to add

```
 dither="yes"
```

option in decoder arguments in order to let decoder work around them. Once you add this option result will be accurate.